# What are the SEO implications of using one domain as home site with additional domains as subdirectories?

Tags: seo, domains, dns

I own three domain names:

- `example.com`
- `example.supply`
- `example.farm`

I want them to behave as if `.supply` and `.farm` are subdirectories, so in the file path it could lay out like so:

```
   public_html (example.com)
   \___
        /supply (example.supply)   
   \___
        /farm (example.farm)
```

What are some of the SEO issues I might run into once set-up?

Comment: I personally do not understand what your goal is. As well, I am not sure there is an advantage in doing this. Can you explain more about your goal/thoughts?

Comment: @closetnoc I was thinking .com would be the main site while the other two handled blog activity and linked back to .com site. I thought some companies do this with .net

Comment: You are then dividing the value that you create over two or more domains- one not benefiting the other. Sub-domains are one thing, but I would still advise against it. Build all your value on one domain and follow the kiss principle. Simple is always best. Do not chase/follow the SEO bull. That is a whole industry designed to confuse, b.s., make themselves look good, keep you guessing/wondering, snag your riches, all the while SEO is just plain simple- pimple stuff. It is not voodoo magic. No self ordained priest/practitioner is required. Just common sense and knowing who has your interest...

Comment: @Shane This is a good question since site operators are buying additional matching domains with the release of the new TLDs. It contained questions that were too broad however so I modified it so it wouldn't be put on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix a single website using different TLDs, they will always be separate sites as on  different domains. So what would be happening is that you have three separate websites.

The SEO issues I see here are that there could be duplication of content between the three sites, so this could affect both sites adversely in search engines rankings of the sites.

Also this could look like you are trying to do something underhand within the search engines, so they might penalise the site for trying to 'game' the search results. They sites could like like doorway pages, or some other spammy type sites.

This could also create confusion and distrust with users, especially if you are interlinking between the sites. If someone clicks what looks like an internal link in the navigation, but goes to another site on a different domain, but looks exactly the same, they may become suspicious and stop browsing both sites.

Comment: I was thinking more or less how you have blog sites that power up a main site but directories close so managing database easy. I guess I can keep on seperate accounts. I actually want to keep sites similar so the user knows I am the same and not some link wheel. But, I have not done SEO in a while so not sure what is considered risky practices.

Comment: @Shane I agree with what Max answered here, in terms of SEO:  _different domains = different sites_. Providing you don't duplicate or use thin content however, you should be fine. The consideration is if you want to build a single _authoritative_ site, or several sites that might spread this out. For ease of administration and marketing, webmasters generally prefer one over many.

Comment: I will likely choose one to focus on and maybe hold onto the others in case the trend starts due to the new TLDs and if there are advantages in the future I have the names locked down.

Comment: It can be a good idea to register other domains fro brand protection too.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely **do not** do this. Google will consider those 3 unique, separate sites and your authority/pagerank will be greatly diminished. So instead of having one site that ranks well, you'll have 3 that rank not-so-well. Seriously, there is no good reason to do this. Do yourself a favor and use one domain.

Comment: Very succinct and well put!